# Loading images from assets.xcassets, into an imageArray, and dynamically load it in a UIImageView, which is present inside a UICollectionView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, xcasset

I'm trying to load a set of images from assets into an image view present inside a UICollectionview, but it shows error whenever I run the application. Also there is no image displayed.

the code I used in `ViewDidLoad` is,

```
var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "bakery")!,
    UIImage(named: "baby")!,
    UIImage(named: "frozen")!,
    UIImage(named: "beauty")!,
    UIImage(named: "cereal")!,
    UIImage(named: "dairy")!,
    UIImage(named: "drinks")!,
    UIImage(named: "fruitsAndVeg")!,
]
```

the code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is,

```
cell.descImage.image = self.logoImage[indexPath.item]
```

When I run the app,I get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "bakery")!,
```

P.S.I imported the images into xcassets from another project, now can that be an issue?

the code breaks up on the above line. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: hide this in `UIImage(named: "bakery")!,` array and try once

Answer (score 0):

When using `!` you unwrap an **optional value**, meaning you are telling the compiler: *I know that the picture is not `nil`*. So, if you lie to the compiler, you get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

if that line:

```
var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "bakery")!,
```

It could be that any of the pictures in the array are missing, but it breaks your program.

You could try and load individual images with conditional statement to locate your issue, and for a better design of your code:

1. Create empty `UIImage` array
2. Create array of `Strings` with the image names
3. Unwrap your image using while looping on the `Strings` array

   ```
   var logoImage = [UIImage]() //1 
   var names: [String] = ["bakery",...] //2

   //3
   for imageName in names{ 
     if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
       logoImage.append(image)
     }
     else {
       print("image named: \(imageName) is missing")
     }
   }
   ```